# Доступ к приватным полям класса

Tags: c++

Каким образом можно получить доступ к приватным полям класса? При этом не используются аксессоры и классы-друзья.

Comment: Глубоко-глубоко было запрятано объявление друга, еще и использование множественного наследования. В общем, вопрос можно закрывать. Но так писать нельзя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только через адреса этих полей.

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
private:
    int a;
    virtual int b ()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
class B
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual int b ();
};
int main()
{
    A obj;
    B* ptr = static_cast<B*>(static_cast<void*>((&obj)));
    ptr->a = 42;
    std::cout<<ptr->b()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет, обращение идет по имени поля.
Как-то это реализовано через указатель и метод с модификатором static. Плюс наследование.

Comment: @Стас Литвиненко отредактировал ответ

Comment: Такой метод уже находил. Но немного не похож на данный случай.
Тут у меня есть static метод, который возвращает указатель на класс. Вызывая этот метод, я получаю доступ к приватным полям.
Явное нарушение принципа инкапсуляции и стандарта плюсов или я чего-то недопонимаю.

Answer (score 8):

Известно 3 способа сделать то, о чем вы просите.

- Задефайнить `#define private public` и подключить соответствующий заголовочный файл *(естественно, бессмысленно в случае `PIMPL`-подобных схем).*
- Напрямую обращаться по предполагаемому адресу переменной (этот способ вам уже рассказали ). Плох тем, что в зависимости от присутствия в классе `vfptr` и `vcbl`, относительное смещение может меняться, т.е способ непортабельный.
- Воспользоваться [**трюком с `template`.**](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm) Самое красивое и даже в некотором плане элегантное решение.

Comment: За template спасибо! Надо будет ознакомиться на досуге.

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int _a) : a(_a) {}
private:
    int a;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(int _b) : b(_b) {}
public:
    int b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a(0);
    ((B*)(&a))->b = 1; // A.a = 1

    return 0;
}
```

То есть, написав параллельно полную копию этого класса, сделав нужные поля пабликовыми.

Comment: Это опять сводится к обращению по адресу. См. выше.

Comment: Ну ведь приватные поля и предназначены для того, чтобы к ним не было доступа помимо аксессоров / методов класса. То, о чём Вы спрашиваете - само по себе явное нарушение стандартов плюсов (насколько я понимаю :).

Comment: Проблема в том, что это каким-то образом реализовано в библиотеке на работе. Переписывать этот кусок под стандарт не дадут. Вот и пытаюсь понять, как реализовано.
Человек, который это писал, уже не работает в том месте.

Comment: "Вызывая этот метод, я получаю доступ к приватным полям" - поясните, как это происходит. Было бы легче, если бы вы привели исходники этого дела, хотя бы часть, и то место, которое вас смущает.

Comment: В данном случае, если в структуре один член, можно написать так: (*(int*)&a)=5;

Answer (score 0):

Недавно у самого была похожая проблема. Изобрёл новый способ. Не знаю подойдёт он тебе или нет. Если у этого класса есть хотя бы один друг(неважно какой, доступный тебе в коде или нет) то ты можешь объявить свой класс с именем, что и имя друга. Пример:

В файле Graphics.h:

```
class Material;
class Graphics
{
public:
    Material* CreateMaterial(Color color)
    {
        Material* material=new Material;
        material->color=color;
        return material;
    }
};
```

В файле Material.h:

```
class Material
{
    friend class Graphics;
private:
    Color color;
};
```

Допустим, у тебя был такой код и ты его не трогаешь. И тут вдруг мы в файле main.cpp объявляем самозванца Graphics:

```
#include "Material.h"
class Graphics
{
    static void ChangeMaterialColor(Material* material, Color newcolor)
    {
        material->color=newcolor;
    }
};
```

Теперь мы можем менять цвет материала при помощи такого самозванца-друга. Единственный момент: два определения Graphics не должны быть объявленыподключены в один cpp-файл, иначе они будут конфликтовать. В моём примере это соблюдается: Material не подключает Graphics, а довольствуется его объявлением.